# document.preventDefault() is not what I need

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, lightbox

I made a website running on an Apache server. The website is only accessed by me. It consists of a drop down list with two options and a "Generate" button. When the button is click, it shows a list of audio elements containing songs. Above each audio element is also a link to the mp3 file itself. I wanted to make a [Lightbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_(JavaScript))
fade in and show the audio element separately when someone clicked on it. I used JQuery to prevent default behaviour when the a tag was clicked, but cannot find a way of only targeting it. This is my problem:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
event.preventDefault();});
```

I have tried changing the `document` part, but it is showing this error: 'Uncaught TypeError: songPlayer.addEventListener is not a function'. Currently, it is targeting all of the document DOM elements, which is not what I want. Is there any other way of achieving this? Also, does anyone have any tips on making lightboxes? Thanks.

Comment: is songPlayer a dom Element?

Comment: paste some sample code so we can help you sort it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addEventListener` needs to be called on a dom element, of soundPlayer has an id of `soundPlayer`:

```
var soundPlayer = document.getElementById('soundPlayer');
```

is what we need,
then we can do:

```
soundPlayer.addEventListener("click", function(event){
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In jquery you do the following:

```
$('#soundPlayer').on('click',function(e){//change #soundPlayer with the css selector of your element
  e.preventDefault();
});
```